# I wrote ZoneDateTime into MySQL 8 using Spring Boot 3.0, and the result differs from when I use Spring Boot 3.1/3.2

Tags: java, spring-boot

Local machine time is [2024-02-22 21:00:00+08:00]

Spring Boot 3.0 is [2024-02-22 21:00:00]

3.1/3.2 is [2024-02-22 13:00:00]

All the code are the same except for the spring boot version.

Why is there such a result?

```
CREATE TABLE Abc (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dt datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Abc")
public class Abc {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private ZonedDateTime dt;
}
```

```
public interface AbcRepository extends CrudRepository<Abc, Integer> {
}
```

```
        Abc abc = new Abc();
        abc.setDt(ZonedDateTime.now());
        abcRepository.save(abc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html

**see**

- OffsetTime mapping changes
- Timezone and offset storage

Answer (score 0):

This result caused by different **hibernate** version. hibernate 6.1 vs 6.2/6.3 /6.4

But I wrote ZonedDateTime into SQL Server 2019, field date type is datetime2.

Results of Spring Boot 3.0/3.1/3.2 are [2024-02-22 21:00:00](Local machine time).

---

Hibernate 6.0/6.1 vs Hibernate 6.2/6.3/6.4

---

MySql：2024-02-23 **09**:14:07 vs 2024-02-23 **01**:14:07, 【hour】 are the same.

SQL Server：2024-02-23 **09**:39:16.4352934 vs 2024-02-23 **09**:39:16.4352934, 【hour】 are different.

Answer (score 0):

use @TimeZoneStorage or hibernate.timezone.default_storage
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/TimeZoneStorage.html